# Run scripts in separate windows

Tags: windows, shell

I want to start shell batches from one single shell window into multiple windows, like this:

start1.bat
start2.bat
start3.bat

Executed from win0;creates win1,win2,win3

OS: windows

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start start1.bat
start start2.bat
start start3.bat
```

Have a look at `start /?` to see what else you can do (set window title, wait for completion, etc.).